# How to merge using outer join if there is common / no common column or unknown column in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, merge

**Problem Statement:** How to perform outer join if we dont have common key (as any additional key appear on

**df_a from json_1:**

```
[
    {
        "bookid": "12345",
        "bookname": "who am i"                 
    }
]
```

**df_b from json_2 :**

```
[
    {
        "bookid": "12345",
        "bookname": "who am i",        
        "Author" : "asp"        
    }
]
```

Now i wanted to find difference between these two datafrmes by each key and value (as i need to write output to html table, each column comparison as seperate df )

**What I tried below** :

```
df1 = pd.merge(df_a[['bookid']],df_b[['bookid']],left_index=True,right_index=True)
df1['diff'] = np.where((df1['bookid_x']==df1['booid_y']),'No', 'Yes') 


df2 = pd.merge(df_a[['bookname']],df_b[['bookname']],left_index=True,right_index=True)
df2['diff'] = np.where((df2['bookname_x']==df2['bookname_y']),'No', 'Yes')

df3 = What should i write here for that unknown column of Author coming from df2 ? 

with open(r"c:\csv\booktest.html", 'w') as _file:     
     _file.write(df1.to_html(index=False) +  "<br>" + df2.to_html(index=False) + "<br>" + df3.to_html(index=False))
```

The problem is df_b data comes from different source, it might have additional column and values (i dont know what is column name would be in well before hand).

**Expected output:** (so when i finally compare two df, for example, as Author column is new column i got from df2 which is not present in df_a it should print NaN there

```
  bookid      bookid       diff
  12345       12345        No

  bookname    bookname     diff
  who am i    who am i     No  
 
  Author      Author       diff
  NaN         asp          Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to align both the data frames so that the columns are same using `.align()`.

```
_, df_a = df_b.align(df_a, fill_value=np.NaN)
_, df_b = df_a.align(df_b, fill_value=np.NaN)
```

Once you do this, both `df_a` and `df_b` will have the same columns.

```
print(df_a)
   Author bookid  bookname
0     NaN  12345  who am i

print(df_b)
  Author bookid  bookname
0    asp  12345  who am i
```

Now you can apply the logic you have to get `df3`

```
df1 = pd.merge(df_a[['bookid']], df_b[['bookid']], left_index=True, right_index=True)
df1['diff'] = np.where((df1['bookid_x']==df1['bookid_y']), 'No', 'Yes')

df2 = pd.merge(df_a[['bookname']], df_b[['bookname']], left_index=True, right_index=True)
df2['diff'] = np.where((df2['bookname_x']==df2['bookname_y']), 'No', 'Yes')

df3 = pd.merge(df_a[['Author']], df_b[['Author']], left_index=True, right_index=True)
df3['diff'] = np.where((df3['Author_x']==df3['Author_y']), 'No', 'Yes')

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)
```

Result:

```
  bookid_x bookid_y diff
0    12345    12345   No
  bookname_x bookname_y diff
0   who am i   who am i   No
   Author_x Author_y diff
0       NaN      asp  Yes
```

**EDIT:**

Ofcourse, you can put your common statements into a loop - for each column in your df

```
for col in df_b.columns:
    df_temp = pd.merge(df_a[[col]], df_b[[col]], left_index=True, right_index=True)
    df_temp['diff'] = np.where((df_temp[col+'_x'] == df_temp[col+'_y']), 'No', 'Yes')
    print(df_temp)
```

Or more effeciently, you can do this - merge both dfs (by all columns) and then find the diff between the pair of columns and export to the html with in the column loop.

```
df_temp = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, left_index=True, right_index=True)
with open(r"booktest.html", 'w') as _file:
    for col in df_a.columns:
        df_temp[col+'_diff'] = np.where((df_temp[col+'_x'] == df_temp[col+'_y']), 'No', 'Yes')
        _file.write(df_temp[[col + '_x', col + '_y', col + '_diff']].to_html(index=False) + "<br>")
print(df_temp)
```

You can also do it without `.merge`, but to get it in the dataframe format in the html, you will have to initialize the dataframe for each column

```
with open(r"booktest.html", 'w') as _file:
    for col in df_a.columns:
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
        df_temp[col + '_x'], df_temp[col + '_y'], df_temp[col + '_diff'] = df_a[col], df_b[col], np.where((df_a[col] == df_b[col]), 'No', 'Yes')
        _file.write(df_temp.to_html(index=False) + "<br>")
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Fixed alignment as per comment

```
text_align = '<style>.dataframe td { text-align: right; }</style>'
with open(r"booktest.html", 'w') as _file:
    for col in df_a.columns:
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
        df_temp[col + '_current'], df_temp[col + '_future'], df_temp[col + '_diff'] = df_a[col], df_b[col], np.where((df_a[col] == df_b[col]), 'No', 'Yes')
        _file.write(text_align + df_temp.to_html(index=False) + "<br>")
    print(df_temp)
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Making a column name as blank if all of its values are `NaN`s

```
text_align = '<style>.dataframe td { text-align: right; }</style>'
with open(r"booktest.html", 'w') as _file:
    for col in df_a.columns:
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
        df_temp[col + '_current'], df_temp[col + '_future'], df_temp[col + '_diff'] = df_a[col], df_b[col], np.where((df_a[col] == df_b[col]), 'No', 'Yes')
        # check if the column values are all NaN and rename the column name
        [df_temp.rename(columns={c:''}, inplace=True) for c in df_temp.columns if df_temp[c].isnull().all()]
        df_temp.fillna('', inplace=True)
        # set  the display width before writing to html so that blank columns are not squeezed
        with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', -1):
            _file.write(text_align+df_temp.to_html(index=False) + "<br>")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, need one more suggestion, as of now, once we align we can know the column name and then like u said, we can fetch value for df3, but in case i dont want to hardcode all the columns one by one manually, is there a way to tell without mentiontin column name, program should take each column possibly by location or position to compare columns ?...can you please let me know how to achieve it...

Comment: hi, i tested it both ways you suggested, without merge and with merge like u mention in both cases it printing that new column when i print it in console but in html i am getting all columns except that new additional which is only there in df_b (i.e author column not coming into html

Comment: @asp I have posted the result I got in the html. Are you sure you have aligned the dfs?

Comment: oh my dumbness..sorry...i just commented those line my mistake..now its working fine...only one more suggestion required, as it printing author_x and author_y column, instead i suffix author_current, author_future as column heading , that should be same like all other columns in html file...how can we do it ?...and  is there a way to right justly all column names and values in html ?

Comment: @asp you can set the suffix as you want instead of '_x' or '_y'. If you want to align the html fields, I guess the option is to use a custom html style and add it to the `.to_html` option.. see edit

Comment: perfect now ...i was struggling like anything with this...solution is simple, neat ;...thank you a ton.. want to become expert like u, need to start somewhere and practice all options... :) Marking your answer as Correct answer

Comment: @asp Thank you!! Glad that I was able to help.

Comment: Hi sorry for asking one more question..it might be vauge requirement..now as we have that author column ..in html its showing like  Author_current Author_Future Difference and avalues as NaN , ASP, yes... i was asked to show blank space for value instead of NaN, so i used df_temp = df_temp.fillna(''), but now i was asked not to show column name also for that Author_Current as its not there at all in source,  fillna only works for value but not column name...any idea...seems to be pretty bad requirement but i was asked to do that way..

Comment: @asp if you want to drop that column that has all `NaN`s, then you can use `df_temp.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)`. This will remove any columns that has all `NaN` values

Comment: @asp see EDIT 3

Comment: Dear pandas god, (its you ) thank you i should be lucky enough to get replies so fast :) , ok so now in html if i use your edit 3 stuff but filling both column name and value as blank but while seeing on browser that frame is so squeezed, so what i did is `df_temp.fillna('', inplace=True)` changed this line to `df_temp.fillna('       ', inplace=True)` to enable extra blank space so that that border of that column extends to reasonable...but border for that blank column still contracted very much.. any idea ?

Comment: hi david, i know its working for you as i see clearly  in your output you updated, somehow, its not working in my case..it still contracted ,it seems only if i fill something like ------ or ..... in this ` df_temp.fillna('', inplace=True) ` border is getting extended for that column name..I know its very weird requirment but thats ok, i came to very reasonable output in hand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216486/discussion-between-asp-and-davidbilla).

Comment: I have slightly different requirement as per above problem which you helped to solved, instead of html i need to write it to json. I have created a separate post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059308/how-to-compare-two-json-and-write-to-third-json-differences-with-pandas-and-nump will you able to assist