# Json file not formatted correctly when writing json differences with pandas and numpy

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to compare two json and then write another json with columns names and with differences as yes or no. I am using pandas and numpy

The below is sample files i am including actually, these json are dynamic, that mean we dont know how many key will be there upfront

**Input files:**

```
fut.json

[
    {
        "AlarmName": "test",
        "StateValue": "OK"
    }
]

Curr.json:

[
    {
        "AlarmName": "test",
        "StateValue": "OK"
    }
]
```

**Below code I have tried:**

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    with open(r"c:\csv\fut.json", 'r+') as f:
        data_b = json.load(f)
    with open(r"c:\csv\curr.json", 'r+') as f:
        data_a = json.load(f)
    df_a = pd.json_normalize(data_a)
    df_b = pd.json_normalize(data_b)
    
    _, df_a = df_b.align(df_a, fill_value=np.NaN)
    _, df_b = df_a.align(df_b, fill_value=np.NaN)
    
    with open(r"c:\csv\report.json", 'w') as _file:
        for col in df_a.columns:
            df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
            df_temp[col + '_curr'], df_temp[col + '_fut'], df_temp[col + '_diff'] = df_a[col], df_b[col], np.where((df_a[col] == df_b[col]), 'No', 'Yes')
            #[df_temp.rename(columns={c:'Missing'}, inplace=True) for c in df_temp.columns if df_temp[c].isnull().all()]
            df_temp.fillna('Missing', inplace=True)
            with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', -1):
                _file.write(df_temp.to_json(orient='records'))
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
    {
        "AlarmName_curr": "test",
        "AlarmName_fut": "test",
        "AlarmName_diff": "No"
    },
    {
        "StateValue_curr": "OK",
        "StateValue_fut": "OK",
        "StateValue_diff": "No"
    }
]
```

**Coming output:** Not able to parse it in json validator, below is the problem, those [] should be replaed by `','` to get right json dont know why its printing like that

```
[{"AlarmName_curr":"test","AlarmName_fut":"test","AlarmName_diff":"No"}][{"StateValue_curr":"OK","StateValue_fut":"OK","StateValue_diff":"No"}]
```

**Edit1:**

Tried below as well

```
_file.write(df_temp.to_json(orient='records',lines=True))
```

now i get json which is again not parsable, ',' is missing and unless i add , between two dic and  [ ] at beginning and end manually , its not parsing..

```
[{"AlarmName_curr":"test","AlarmName_fut":"test","AlarmName_diff":"No"}{"StateValue_curr":"OK","StateValue_fut":"OK","StateValue_diff":"No"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly pandas is overkill for this... however

1. load dataframes as you did
2. concat them as columns.  rename columns
3. do calcs and map boolean to desired Yes/No
4. `to_json()` returns a string so `json.loads()` to get it back into a list/dict. Filter columns to get to your required format

```
import json
data_b = [
    {
        "AlarmName": "test",
        "StateValue": "OK"
    }
]
data_a = [
    {
        "AlarmName": "test",
        "StateValue": "OK"
    }
]
df_a = pd.json_normalize(data_a)
df_b = pd.json_normalize(data_b)
df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], axis=1)
df.columns = [c+"_curr" for c in df_a.columns] + [c+"_fut" for c in df_a.columns]
df["AlarmName_diff"] = df["AlarmName_curr"] == df["AlarmName_fut"]
df["StateValue_diff"] = df["StateValue_curr"] == df["StateValue_fut"]
df = df.replace({True:"Yes", False:"No"})
js = json.loads(df.loc[:,(c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("Alarm"))].to_json(orient="records"))
js += json.loads(df.loc[:,(c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("State"))].to_json(orient="records"))
js
```

**output**

```
[{'AlarmName_curr': 'test', 'AlarmName_fut': 'test', 'AlarmName_diff': 'Yes'},
 {'StateValue_curr': 'OK', 'StateValue_fut': 'OK', 'StateValue_diff': 'Yes'}]
```

Comment: Hi @Rob Raymond , just need a small suggestion, the json inputs are variable in nature, i am comparing many json(those are json files) like this, where number of columns are dynamic in that, case i am bit confused about last two line in your code.. ideally my requirement is loop through all columns where we dont know number of column up front in each json file which we compare and then write output to json..

Comment: It's all to do with your requirement to split "Alarm" and "State" into separate dicts in final list.  I could have as easily made this a list and looped over it as well.  If you look `df` is only one record,  so I've mashed sets of columns into rows in output

Comment: Yeah, my apologies, i could have mentioned in question that items are dynamic in each source json. for example i have included those two inputs jsons. Its my mistake.. yeah..i have different sets of json, which have different number of columns i need to run this program against each set.

Comment: can you help how to do loop through ad then compare (especially json method u used)  if number of columns are dynamic in source json files.